# LDAP search in script results in "DNS SRV: out of memory"

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to write a script that will declare txt file & a specified server, run an LDAP query, and put the output in the txt file, but I am getting an error DNS SRV: out of memory? It is a CentOS 7 VM and has 8GB RAM.

```
#!/bin/bash -x

# Declare vars
outFile="file/path"
dc="my.dc.com"

# Run openldap query
hosts=$(ldapsearch -b "ou=my,dc=ou,dc=path" -H ldap://{$dc} | grep dNSHostName)

# echo to file to test
echo {$hosts} >&2 {$outFile}
exit 0
```

This is the output I get:

```
+ outFile=file/path
+ dc=my.dc.com
++ ldapsearch -b "ou=my,dc=ou,dc=path" -H 'ldap://{my.dc.com}'
++ grep dNSHostName
DNS SRV: out of memory?
+ hosts=
+ echo '{}' '{file/path}'
{} {file/path}
+ exit 0
```

However, when I run just the LDAP query outside of the script, it returns successfully.

The dc has 16GB of RAM. I monitored the RAM during the query and no visible spikes were observed.

EDIT:

```
[prompt]$ ldapsearch -b "ou=my,dc=ou,dc=path" -H ldap://my.dc.com | grep dNSHostName
SASL/GSSAPI authentication started
SASL username: user@domain.com
SASL SSF: 256
SASL data security layer installed.
dNSHostName: hostname1.com
dNSHostName: hostname2.com
dNSHostName: hostname3.com
dNSHostName: hostname4.com
dNSHostName: hostname5.com
dNSHostName: hostname6.com
dNSHostName: hostname7.com
```

Comment: Note to those who vote to close: this issue is not about the LDAP server. It involves a misleading error message from the LDAP client but the root cause is a programming error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [a bug opened on bugzilla.redhat.com](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1722590) that refers to your issue, but it's not going to be fixed. The error message (`DNS SRV: out of memory?`) is probably misleading and **it might just be that the LDAP client failed to resolve the server name**.

The server URL in your script is `ldap://{$dc}` but your command line (which works), doesn't include the curly brackets. Try this:

```
 hosts=$(ldapsearch -b "ou=my,dc=ou,dc=path" -H "ldap://$dc" | grep dNSHostName)
```

It seems to me you don't know how to use a variable in Bourne shell. The proper syntax is `"${variable}"` (or just `"$variable"` if there is no ambiguity). The double quotes are not strictly necessary but I strongly advise you to always expand variables inside double quotes, unless you must not (rare cases that you will recognize when they will occur).

Thus, also replace this:

```
echo {$hosts} >&2 {$outFile}
```

with this:

```
echo "$hosts" >&2 "$outFile"
```

or this:

```
echo "${hosts}" >&2 "${outFile}"
```

Comment: Thanks so much!!! My extent of experience with bash is minimal. I am just now getting into bash after much experience in Powershell. It works now. I appreciate your help!

Comment: @anthony.kellar Glad I could help. You understand now why I insisted that you remove your pseudo-values. It was difficult to figure out whether `<server>` and `{server}` were actual code or not. Now your mistake appears clearly.

Comment: I absolutely understand! I have not posted a lot of code on forums before. Still new to the experience! :)